# Terraform ACM doesn't validate Route 53 DNS

Tags: terraform

I've created a Route 53 DNS using Terraform and assigned a certificate with ACM.. although when trying to verify the code is stuck in a loop `aws_acm_certificate_validation.verify: Still creating... [27m31s elapsed]`

## main.tf

```
# ACM Certificate 
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "ssl" {
  domain_name       = "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Route53 Zone
resource "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name = "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  private_zone = false
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  zone_id      = aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
}

# Route53 Record
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.ssl.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
}

# ACM Validation
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "verify" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.ssl.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.www : record.fqdn]
}

# ALB Listener
resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate_validation.verify.certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb-target.arn
  }
}
```

I verified there's a hosted zone using the aws cli

aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id Z03171471QBEVDH2KPJ6W

```
{
    "HostedZone": {
        "Id": "/hostedzone/Z03171471QBEVDH2KPJ6W",
        "Name": "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com.",
        "CallerReference": "terraform-20221202175826093600000001",
        "Config": {
            "Comment": "Managed by Terraform",
            "PrivateZone": false
        },
    },
    "DelegationSet": {
        "NameServers": [
            "ns-566.awsdns-06.net",
            "ns-1336.awsdns-39.org",
            "ns-212.awsdns-26.com",
            "ns-1559.awsdns-02.co.uk"
        ]
    }
}
```

aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z03171471QBEVDH2KPJ6W

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z03171471QBEVDH2KPJ6W
{
    "ResourceRecordSets": [
        {
            "Name": "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com.",
            "Type": "NS",
            "TTL": 172800,
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "ns-566.awsdns-06.net."
                },
                {
                    "Value": "ns-1336.awsdns-39.org."
                },
                {
                    "Value": "ns-212.awsdns-26.com."
                },
                {
                    "Value": "ns-1559.awsdns-02.co.uk."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com.",
```

Following this documentation [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation) with a slight change, It didnt work when I tried to provide only an aws_route53_zone of data type so I added a resource and pointed the data to it.

I literally tried everything in the extent of my knowledge and in need of help. I stumbled upon other posts on stackoverflow with the same problem but none had a proper anwser.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to have both the `data` and `resource` for the Route53 zone in your Terraform code. Delete the `data` and just use the `resource`. The reason your SSL certificate isn't validating is most likely because you just created a public zone in Route53 without actually doing the part at your Domain Registrar to configure that Route53 zone as the authoritative DNS server for that domain or subdomain. If the domain validation record doesn't show up here: https://dnschecker.org/ then Amazon's ACM service won't be able to find it either.

Comment: I've actually tried to verify our other domain `cclab.cloud-castles.com` which does show on the website when you look it up.. still no avail

Comment: The DNS record that ACM tells you to create, shows up when you check it at dnscheker.org, but ACM still fails to valid the certificate?

Comment: I was under the assumption that Route 53 creates the DNS record and the acm_certificate just creates the certificate.. while validation validates it against the DNS

Comment: ACM validates that you actually own the domain name you are trying to create an SSL certificate for. It doesn't work if you setup a Route53 zone that isn't wired up to your domain registrar. Anyone could create any domain in Route53, but you have to wire it up to your domain registrar so it actually resolves on the Internet before ACM will allow you to create a certificate for that domain.

Comment: I get your point thanks, I will have to wait with it those are quite expensive and I would like to make sure with my senior :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create an alias for my ALB. only the certificate was issued a record

the solution was to issue an alias of type 'A' for apex domains (no www header)

heres a snipet of what worked for me

```
# Route 53 - Certificate Record
resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.ssl.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
}

# Route 53 - ALB Alias
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_route53_record" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
  name    = "modules.cclab.cloud-castles.com"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = aws_lb.alb.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_lb.alb.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```